What is the difference between cder versus open fda /drug/ndc data?
Is the data available via https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/cder/ndctext.zip
the same as what can be downloaded from open FDA /drug/ndc data
The two files are in different formats.
I am asking if the drug list available between each file is the same -e.g. do each have the same products and packages?
In another issue, it was stated that open FDA versus cder have different update schedules.  Can you confirm how big the time difference is?  My understanding is that the access cder data is updated daily at 6 am eastern time.  How often and what time is open FDA updated?

Yes, the NDC dataset matches between CDER and openFDA (in fact, ndctext.zip is used as an input to openFDA pipelines) and is updated daily.
